# Play! 2.0 hangs with JDK 1.7 on Mac OS X

Tags: playframework, java-7, playframework-2.0

Have you experienced Play applications hanging when you run them under JDK 1.7?

When I start Play application with it the first request that checks for database evolutions and applies those but after that no requests goes through. I'm puzzled what could be causing this.

Comment: Yes. Stop using JDK 7 with Play 2.0 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to [Play 2.0.2](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Home) appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with the combination of play! 2.x, MacOS X and the JDK7.
Interestingly, this occured to me when using play! 2.0.1 but not with v. 2.0.
This was reproducable.

As Seymour Cakes mentioned, a switch back to Java 6 solved the issues, even for play! 2.0.1.

For more information, see also: [Play framework 2.0.1 - Server only responding to the first requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452122/play-framework-2-0-1-server-only-responding-to-the-first-requests)