# Play framework 2.0.1 - Server only responding to the first requests

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a strange behavior with either Play 2.0 or 2.0.1 : the first or
first few requests are served quickly by the Play! server, but then
it's not responding anymore.

I reproduced the problem on several projects including the hello word sample application :
- lauching "play run"
- Go to http://localhost:9000 -> ok
- Hit refresh a few times : the requests are locked, the browser is
just loading.

I have the same behavior with Firefox and Chrome.

I guess it's a setup problem, and I may be missing something trivial,
but I can't see what.

I 'm using Mac OS X Lion and Java 7 update 4.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: I tried setting my path to Java 6, without any change.

Comment: Can not reproduce, I saw similar problem somewhere and there the blocker was just external resources in HTML's head which where 'hanging' page rendering, use `FireBug` > `Net` to check if there is no such in your case.

Comment: Thank you.

I'm testing in a sample projet and a simple template where there's absolutely nothing but a hello.

Comment: It seems that there can only be a connection by browser. 

I have the same thing with a java client (HttpUrlConnection), the first request is ok, then it blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you.

It was indeed related to Java 7. I finally got it working, it took me a couple of hours to find out how.

It seems that having the JAVA_HOME variable defined to the Java 7 path is generating some conflict.

Commenting the export line in my .bashrc solved the problem :

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/raphaellemaire/tools/play-2.0.1

#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 1):

It is known that Play reacts weirdly when using Jdk 7. Check the mailing list, several issues have been noticed.

Seems like the only viable solution IMO. (Using same setup as you otherwise and no problems at all)

Comment: Here's the cooresponding [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/411-play-20-server-hangs-under-java-7-on-mac-os-x) in play's issues list. It seems fixed in 2.0.2, but they still search for the checkin that fixed it ...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to [Play 2.0.2](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Home) appears to work, as mentioned in mkeoller's comment.